# Sorting content in Ngb-Accordion

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here's the code for the **accordion**:

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="false" activeIds="0">
        <ng-container class="card" *ngFor="let post of Posts">
            <ngb-panel title="{{post.title}} - By: {{post.author}}, At: {{post.datePosted}}" id="{{post.id}}">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    {{post.about}}
                    <hr>
                    <button (click)="navigateTo(post.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Comments</button>
                </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
        </ng-container>
    </ngb-accordion>
```

What I'd like to do is basically **sorting** the accordion's content by **`{{post.datePosted}}`** so the **first item** in the list would be the one posted **recently**.

If you have any ideas or suggestions... please.
Right now I store the dates int he Posts array like this:

```
var x = new Date();
var y = x.getFullYear().toString();
var m = (x.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var d = x.getDate().toString();
var h = x.getHours().toString();
var min = x.getMinutes();
(d.length == 1) && (d = '0' + d);
(m.length == 1) && (m = '0' + m);
var date = y+"." + m+"." + d+" "+h+":"+min;
```

And the array definition:

```
export class Post {
  id: number;
  cim: string;
  leir: string;
  iro: string;
  mikor: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you will have to sort the data in the `.ts` file itself and then display in the front-end like this:

In `.ts` file:

```
let sortedPosts = this.Posts.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.datePosted).getTime() - new Date(b.datePosted).getTime()));
```

In `.html` use `sortedPosts` instead of `Posts` like this:

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="false" activeIds="0">
        <ng-container class="card" *ngFor="let post of sortedPosts">
            <ngb-panel title="{{post.title}} - By: {{post.author}}, At: {{post.datePosted}}" id="{{post.id}}">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    {{post.about}}
                    <hr>
                    <button (click)="navigateTo(post.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Comments</button>
                </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
        </ng-container>
    </ngb-accordion>
```

For more info on date comparison see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/5349542).

Comment: I see, then so I have to store the datePosted's in an integer? Because now it's something like this:var x = new Date();
var y = x.getFullYear().toString();
var m = (x.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var d = x.getDate().toString();
var h = x.getHours().toString();
var min = x.getMinutes();
(d.length == 1) && (d = '0' + d);
(m.length == 1) && (m = '0' + m);
var date = y+"." + m+"." + d+" "+h+":"+min;

Comment: @Skickpause not necessarily. You can use `new Date()` as constructor. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you captain! You have my greatest deepest gratitude. :)

Answer (score 0):

import * as _ from 'lodash';
this.sortedPosted= _.sortBy(this.posts, p => p.datePosted);